# How to make a continues slide window time checking by Drools?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

My case is: If the sum of withdraw of my bank account is greater than 1000$ within any continues 10 mins, E.g., 0m-10m and then 0m1s-10m1s, then 0m2s-10m2s, which is a sliding time window, the bank system should send me a warning message.

So, can anyone help me writing the rule by Drools?

My initial idea is below:

```
when
              Number( $total : intValue, intValue >= 1000)
              from accumulate (Withdraw ($money : money)
              over window:time( 10m )
              from entry-point ATMEntry,
              sum($money))
then
    System.out.println("Warning! too more withdraw:"+$total);
```

However, it will just check the upcoming 10m for one time. After the first 10m, no matter how many withdraw object that I insert to ATMEntry are, I will not receive the warning message.

And if I fire above rule interval in different session, for example every 1m, it makes me confused about how to insert withdraw object to ATMEntry for different session.

So, is that possible to use Drools to in my case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger the evaluation by another Withdraw event:

```
when
          Withdraw()
          Number( $total : intValue >= 1000)
              from accumulate (Withdraw ($money : money)
                   over window:time( 10m )
                   from entry-point ATMEntry,
                   sum($money))
then
    System.out.println( "Warning! " + $total );
end
```

If you need the individual events it might be better to collect them into a list. This can also help to close one interval with excess withdrawal and open another one. It depends on the details of the spec: when to raise an alaram, and when to raise - or raise not - the next alarm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I do not know when the next event will come. So, I could not collect them into a list.

So, I need drools to observer every 10 min. For example, 0m-10m and then 0m1s-10m1s, then 0m2s-10m2s, which is a sliding window. And I just feed each events in one session one ATMEntry at real-time.

Can Drools support this feature?

Comment: You can write a rule that fires when a Withdraw comes. Then you can look for others within the last 10 minutes. - If you look at fixed times you can miss something.

Comment: So, you mean that I need to fire the rule when a new Withdraw comes, is that right? And how about the session? If I must use the same session to fire it?

Comment: With these scenarios you typically need one session that is continuously running. But you may not need to do fraud detection in real time - you can't send the posse out to the ATM anyway. If you run this app periodically, you'll have to make sure that the interruptions are handled correctly, i.e., without missing an excess overdraft.